# Get input shape in tf.keras.Model (Imperative API)

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I use Tensorflow 2.0 and I have a model that was defined in Imperative API. In call method I use something like this:

```py
b, h, w, c = images.shape
k_h, k_w = kernels.shape[2], kernels.shape[3]

images = tf.transpose(images, [1, 2, 0, 3])  # (h, w, b, c)
new_shape = tf.TensorShape([1, h, w, b * c])
images = tf.reshape(images, new_shape)
```

When I train my model with custom loop -- no problem. But I want to porting my model to SavedModel format. I use the following function:

```py
tf.keras.experimental.export_saved_model(
        model, file_path,
        serving_only=True,
        input_signature=[
                tf.TensorSpec(shape=[None, None, None, 3], dtype=tf.float32),
            ]
        )
```

And i got error:

```py
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

Moreover, I can't do it even If I specify shape=[1, None, None, 3], because I got:

```
ValueError: Tried to convert 'shape' to a tensor and failed. Error: Cannot convert a partially known TensorShape to a Tensor: (1, None, None, 3)
```

It means that I can't do reshape at all. But I need it. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running in graph mode use tf.shape.
tf.Tensor.shape fails automatic shape inference when runnning in graph mode.
Here is the code with necessary changes made.

```
image_shape = tf.shape(images)
kernel_shape = tf.shape(kernels)
b, h, w, c = image_shape[0], image_shape[1], image_shape[2], image_shape[3], 
k_h, k_w = kernel_shape[2], kernel_shape[3]

images = tf.transpose(images, [1, 2, 0, 3])  # (h, w, b, c)
new_shape = tf.TensorShape([1, h, w, b * c])
images = tf.reshape(images, new_shape)
```

Comment: I got another problem: `ValueError: Ambiguous dimension: tf.Tensor(128, shape=(), dtype=int32)` in line where `b * c`, i.e `new_shape = tf.TensorShape([1, h, w, b * c])`